# Неверное форматирование html письма

Tags: html, форматирование

Я пытаюсь кривыми руками собрать html письмо. Но в тело письма попадает html разметка как Текст.

```
                    if ( label !== undefined && label !== null && item_val > 0) {
                    quote += ( '<div id="fo" style="width:100%;float:left;margin-bottom:-1px;"><div style="background-color:#f2f7fb;float:left;width:45%;padding:5px;border:1px solid #d1eaff;margin-right:-1px;font-size:15px;color:#464646;">'+ label + '</div><div style="float:left;width:10%;padding:5px;border:1px solid #d1eaff;text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:#464646;background-color:#f2f7fb;font-weight:bold;">'+  item_val + '</div></div>' ) + "\r\n";
                }
```

Я так понимаю, форматирование отключено?
Я второй день пытаюсь найти пример как это сделать, но мог смотреть и не понимать.
Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему...

```
            // CF 7 support

        c.find( '.wpcf7-submit' ).click(function() {

            var val = true;
            var quote = '';

            c.find( '.btQuoteItem' ).each(function() {
                var item_val = 0;
                var selected_name = '';

                $( this ).find( '.btQuoteText' ).each(function() {
                    item_val = bt_parse_float( $( this ).val() );
                });

                $( this ).find( '.btQuoteSelect' ).find( '._msddli_.selected' ).each(function() {
                    selected_name = $( this ).find( '.ddlabel' )[0].innerHTML;
                    if ( $( this ).is( ':first-child' ) ) {
                        selected_name = '';
                    }
                    item_val = bt_parse_float( $( this ).data( 'value' ) );
                });

                var is_slider = false;
                var slider_val;
                $( this ).find( '.btQuoteSlider' ).each(function() {
                    var unit_price = bt_parse_float( $( this ).data( 'price' ) );
                    // slider_val = bt_parse_float( $( this ).slider( 'value' ) );
                    slider_val = bt_cc_get_slider_value ( $( this ) );
                    item_val = slider_val * unit_price;
                    is_slider = true;
                });

                $( this ).find( '.btQuoteSwitch' ).each(function() {
                    if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'on' ) ) {
                        item_val = bt_parse_float( $( this ).data( 'on' ) );
                    } else {
                        item_val = bt_parse_float( $( this ).data( 'off' ) );
                    }
                });

                var label = $( this ).find( 'label' ).html();

                if ( is_slider ) {
                    label = label + ' (' + slider_val + ') ' ;
                }                       

                if ( selected_name != '' ) {
                    selected_name = selected_name.replace( '<span class="description">', '/' );
                    selected_name = selected_name.replace( '</span>', '' );
                    label = label + ' (' + selected_name + ') ';
                }

                item_val = bt_cc_currency_format( c, item_val );

                if ( label !== undefined && label !== null && item_val > 0) {
                    quote += ('<div id="fo" style="width:100%;float:left;margin-bottom:-1px;"><div style="background-color:#f2f7fb;float:left;width:45%;padding:5px;border:1px solid #d1eaff;margin-right:-1px;font-size:15px;color:#464646;">'+ label + '</div><div style="float:left;width:10%;padding:5px;border:1px solid #d1eaff;text-align:right;font-size:15px;color:#464646;background-color:#f2f7fb;font-weight:bold;">'+  item_val + '</div></div>' ) + "\r\n";
                }


            });
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Очень детальное описание проблемы :)

Comment: Извините, спешил) В общем, в тело письма попадает сама html разметка...

Comment: Ситуация не изменилась :( Что за переменная quote? Что за код? Где отображается письмо?

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: [вставка HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Спасибо Владислав что помогаете! Я попытался реализовать ваш пример, но не вышло, где-то я делаю ошибки...

Comment: Если бы Вы дали более детальное объяснения.. `quote` - это само письмо? Оно выводится пользователю в браузер? (если Да, то код вывода предоставьте).